# Model Train Start Point

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I would like to set a start point before training cnn. How to set a starting point for a model? Here is my code. Also I wonder if starting point changes each time I retrain the model? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(16, 5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_path= "sentiment labelled sentences/imdb models/model{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
check=ModelCheckpoint(model_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto',save_freq='epoch') #modeli her epoch sonunda kaydet
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=15,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=10, callbacks=[check])
```

Comment: By setting a starting point do you mean fixing the initial values of the weights?

Comment: yes I do, I also wonder if initial weight change everytime I run the model

Comment: Yes they will change every time as they are initialized with random numbers. If you want to make sure that the model always uses the same initial weights you need to fix the random seed, see [`tf.random.set_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed). Otherwise you can initialize the weights using a constant value instead of random values, see [`tf.keras.initializers.Constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Constant).

Answer (score 0):

As you typed out your neural network model is `Sequential()`, meaning the first layer is where your model starts (i.e. `model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))`)

If you want to have a different input layer, you can just rearrange the lines of code, or code another one.

If you're looking to debug or just start execution midway thru your neural network, I don't think that's possible. This is an issue neural networks have. They are not very interpretable/explainable, meaning they're like a blackbox. You cannot look inside and check out how, for a certain set of datapoints, a NN reaches a prediction. I found this website article expanding on this issue: https://www.altacognita.com/explainability-in-deep-neural-networks-2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think editing input layer will work fine. But I wonder how to edit it, because I don't set a specific start point..

Comment: Edit it depending on what your goal is: you can change hyperparameters (the keyword args) or give it a different input altogether. Also a Conv1D layer is for images, and the the Embedding layer is more for encoding words. You gotta make sure you're clear on what component layers do and what you want your neural network to achieve.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question celarly.. I do not want to change my model architecture.